# Rails - How to join results form two AR queries into one object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I combine the following two AR objects (returned from two individual queries):

```
user1 = User.first
```

and

```
user2 = User.last
```

into a proper AREL object like:

```
@users = user1, user2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is ok: `@users = [user1, user2]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@users = user1 + user2
```

I know this works on an array of objects retrieved from the database, not sure about single objects though.

Otherwise maybe something like the following will work:

```
@users = [] << user1 << user2
```